# ArcGIS javascript API Update Records of a Feature Layer

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm new to ArcGIS javascript API, now I want to create a feature layer and then add an array of attributes or simply update the array of attributes of a specific field. I only need to replace the original values array as my own array. Is that possible? 
There's a method: attr(name,value), Can I use this? 
Can any one give me some hints or code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

i'd start by taking a look at the sample below, which demonstrates the use of a widget that simplifies the process of passing attribute edits back to ArcGIS Server.

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/ed_attribute_inspector.html

if you aren't interested in using one of the APIs widgets, you can also make your own calls to featureLayer.applyEdits()

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#applyedits.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't want to use the Editor Widget. How to set the layer editable? I'm still confused about how to use applyEdits() method. Can you give me some example? Thank you!